# Efficacy of snorkel mask defogging agent on safety glasses

Tags: snorkeling

Will the de-fogging agent for snorkeling/scuba goggles prevent or mitigate steaming up of safety glasses worn outside on a hot, humid day?

Comment: there are products for skying goggles that might suit you better...

Comment: @Erik vanDoren Willing to try...but why do you think so?

Comment: The stuff I have for my goggles is pretty "dry" and less "delicate" compared to what I have for my scuba mask, and my safety glasses lenses get pretty dusty and sweaty. But I hear quite a few people using the shampoo, also heard of people rubbing a piece of raw potato or onion on the lenses, cheaper to try than commercial stuff anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defogging a dive mask is usually done with a soap solution. You get two effects that help keep moisture from forming on the glass: cleaning and a soap residue. Baby shampoo works for me, is cheaper than specially branded mask defogger, and smells baby fresh to boot. I've used it on my prescription lenses and on sunglasses. I haven't actually used it on safety glasses. (I do my woodworking inside.) But I know of no reason why cleaning your safety glasses with mild soap like baby shampoo will harm them. So it should be really easy for you to test in your current, sweaty environment.

Comment: brilliant idea!